# How do I make the hoverable dropdown close when navigating to a differerent link in Bulma?

Tags: vue.js, hover, dropdown, nuxt.js, bulma

[HERE is a SANDBOX with the issue on it](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-perlman-b014x)

- I have a hoverable dropdown inside a Navbar
- When I move to a different page, the dropdown is still open
- I have tried this in plain Bulma, the issue still remains
- I am on Nuxt.js using SSR
- I am using nuxt-link / equivalent of Vue router-link to navigate to a different page.

**Here is the my default.vue file**

```
<template>
  <div class="ch-container">
    <header class="ch-header">
      <nav
        class="navbar is-fixed-top"
        role="navigation"
        aria-label="main navigation"
      >
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <nuxt-link class="navbar-item" to="/">
            <img
              alt="CH Logo"
              src="https://i.imgur.com/v35Kfc9.png"
              width="28"
              height="28"
            />
          </nuxt-link>

          <a
            role="button"
            class="navbar-burger burger"
            aria-label="menu"
            aria-expanded="false"
            data-target="navbarBasicExample"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar-start">
            <nuxt-link class="navbar-item" to="/news">
              News
            </nuxt-link>

            <nuxt-link class="navbar-item" to="/resources">
              Resources
            </nuxt-link>

            <nuxt-link class="navbar-item" to="/tickers">
              Tickers
            </nuxt-link>

            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
              <a class="navbar-link">
                More
              </a>
              <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  FAQ
                </a>
                <nuxt-link class="navbar-item" to="/contact">
                  Contact
                </nuxt-link>
                <hr class="navbar-divider" />
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Feature Request
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="navbar-end">
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <a href="#">
                <fa :icon="faMoon" />
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
              <a class="navbar-link is-arrowless">
                <fa :icon="faExclamationCircle" />
              </a>
              <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  No new notifications
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <div class="buttons">
                <nuxt-link class="button is-primary" to="/signup">
                  <strong>Sign up</strong>
                </nuxt-link>
                <nuxt-link id="login" class="button is-light" to="/login">
                  Log in
                </nuxt-link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="ch-main">
      <nuxt />
    </main>
    <footer class="ch-footer is-hidden-mobile">
      <div class="level">
        <div class="level-left">
          <div class="level-item">
            <a href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <fa :icon="faFacebookSquare" />
              </span>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <fa :icon="faTwitterSquare" />
              </span>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <fa :icon="faRedditSquare" />
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="level-right">
          <div class="level-item">
            &copy;ch, All Rights Reserved
          </div>
          <div class="level-item">
            <nuxt-link to="/contact">Contact</nuxt-link>
          </div>
          <div class="level-item">
            <nuxt-link to="/terms-of-service">Terms</nuxt-link>
          </div>
          <div class="level-item">
            <nuxt-link to="/privacy-policy">Privacy</nuxt-link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  faFacebookSquare,
  faTwitterSquare,
  faRedditSquare,
} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

import { faMoon, faExclamationCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

export default {
  computed: {
    faFacebookSquare() {
      return faFacebookSquare
    },
    faTwitterSquare() {
      return faTwitterSquare
    },
    faRedditSquare() {
      return faRedditSquare
    },
    faMoon() {
      return faMoon
    },
    faExclamationCircle() {
      return faExclamationCircle
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
    const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(
      document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'),
      0
    )

    // Check if there are any navbar burgers
    if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {
      // Add a click event on each of them
      $navbarBurgers.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
          // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
          const target = el.dataset.target
          const $target = document.getElementById(target)

          // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
          el.classList.toggle('is-active')
          $target.classList.toggle('is-active')
        })
      })
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

**Here is a GIF illustrating the problem**

[image]

How to close the dropdown after you move to a different page?

Comment: Any working code?? repo!!!?

Comment: @HardikShah https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-perlman-b014x modified the question as well to include a sandbox with the problem, try navigating to a different page from the more dropdown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the whole thing makes it complicated, because the hover is triggered by css and therefore the dropdown can always be seen when the mouse is over it. You have to overwrite this state and solve it with vue events. We also have to put a watcher on the route to reset the state.

[CodeSandbox - Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bulma-hover-vbn56?file=/layouts/default.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <!-- <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io"> -->
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">

        <a
          role="button"
          class="navbar-burger burger"
          aria-label="menu"
          aria-expanded="false"
          data-target="navbarBasicExample"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <a class="navbar-item">Home</a>

          <a class="navbar-item">Documentation</a>

          <div
            @mouseover="toggleDropdown(true)"
            @mouseleave="toggleDropdown(false)"
            class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable"
          >
            <a class="navbar-link">More</a>

            <div class="navbar-dropdown" :style="{display: showDropdown ? 'block' : 'none' }">
              <nuxt-link class="navbar-item" to="/about">About</nuxt-link>
              <nuxt-link class="navbar-item" to="/jobs">Jobs</nuxt-link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-end">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div class="buttons">
              <a class="button is-primary">
                <strong>Sign up</strong>
              </a>
              <a class="button is-light">Log in</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <Nuxt/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      routeChange: false,
      showDropdown: false
    };
  },

  watch: {
    $route() {
      this.routeChange = true;
      this.showDropdown = false;
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleDropdown(payload) {
      if (this.showDropdown !== payload) this.routeChange = false;
      if (!this.routeChange) {
        this.showDropdown = payload;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked form me Bootstrap 5, in touch devices it uses click, on devices with mouse it uses hover

```
<template>
  <span
    v-if="item"
    class="primary-navigation-list-dropdown"
    @mouseover="isTouchscreenDevice ? null : openDropdownMenu()"
    @mouseleave="isTouchscreenDevice ? null : closeDropdownMenu()"
  >
    <nuxt-link
      to="#"
      @click.prevent.native="openDropdownMenu"
      v-click-outside="closeDropdownMenu"
      :title="item.title"
      :class="[
        item.cssClasses,
        { show: isDropdownMenuVisible }
      ]"
      :id="`navbarDropdownMenuLink-${item.id}`"
      :aria-expanded="[isDropdownMenuVisible ? true : false]"
      class="
        primary-navigation-list-dropdown__toggle
        nav-link
        dropdown-toggle"
      aria-current="page"
      role="button"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
    >
      {{ item.label }}
    </nuxt-link>
    <ul
      :class="{ show: isDropdownMenuVisible }"
      :aria-labelledby="`navbarDropdownMenuLink-${item.id}`"
      class="
        primary-navigation-list-dropdown__menu
        dropdown-menu-list
        dropdown-menu"
    >
      <li
        v-for="item in item.children" :key="item.id"
        class="dropdown-menu-list__item"
      >
        <NavLink
          :attributes="item"
          class="dropdown-menu-list__link dropdown-item"
        />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
import NavLink from '@/components/Navigation/NavLink';

export default {
  name: "DropdownMenu",
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isDropdownMenuVisible: false,
      isTouchscreenDevice: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.detectTouchscreenDevice();
  },
  methods: {
    openDropdownMenu() {
      if (this.isTouchscreenDevice) {
        this.isDropdownMenuVisible = !this.isDropdownMenuVisible;
      } else {
        this.isDropdownMenuVisible = true;
      }
    },

    closeDropdownMenu() {
      if (this.isTouchscreenDevice) {
        this.isDropdownMenuVisible = false;
      } else {
        this.isDropdownMenuVisible = false;
      }
    },

    detectTouchscreenDevice() {
      if (window.PointerEvent && ('maxTouchPoints' in navigator)) {
        if (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) {
          this.isTouchscreenDevice = true;
        }
      } else {
        if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(any-pointer:coarse)").matches) {
          this.isTouchscreenDevice = true;
        } else if (window.TouchEvent || ('ontouchstart' in window)) {
          this.isTouchscreenDevice = true;
        }
      }
      return this.isTouchscreenDevice;
    }
  },
  components: {
    NavLink
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.primary-navigation-list-dropdown {
  &__toggle {
    color: $white;

    &:hover {
      color: $blue;
    }
  }

  &__menu {
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  &__dropdown {

  }
}

.dropdown-menu-list {
  &__item {

  }

  &__link {
    &.active,
    &.nuxt-link-exact-active {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $blue;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

NavLink.vue

```
<template>
  <component
    :is="attributes"
    v-bind="linkAttributes(attributes.path)"
    :title="attributes.title"
    :class="[ attributes.cssClasses ]"
    class="nav-link active_"
    aria-current="page"
    prefetch
  >
  {{ attributes.label }}
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'NavLink',
  props: {
    attributes: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    linkAttributes(path) {
      if (path.match(/^(http(s)?|ftp):\/\//) || path.target === '_blank') {
        return {
          is: 'a',
          href: path,
          target: '_blank',
          rel: 'noopener'
        }
      }
      return {
        is: 'nuxt-link',
        to: path
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

click-outside.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
      if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
      }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m not using Vue, but using Meteor (where similar route-calling trips up the Bulma drop-down removal).

Slightly hacky way to fix it, but the dropdown is made visible because the .has-dropdown element has the .is-hoverable class. So to fix, on any click on the dropdown’s items, I run this:

```
// Remove the hover effect = dropdown disappears    
$(".has-dropdown").removeClass("is-hoverable");
// Tiny time later, put it back, so hover-drop works anew
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".has-dropdown").addClass("is-hoverable");
}, 100);
```

Doesn’t really matter that it would hit all the dropdowns if you have more than one, because resetting them all is harmless when routing to a new page. But if you’re fussy you could target just the closest dropdown.

As Bulma’s mobile view doesn’t activate an on-hover effect anyway, this doesn’t break in the mobile “burger menu” version of my navbar.

Works OK for my project on Chrome, Safari, Firefox.